# Windows 10 upgrade from Windows 8.1 freezes during "configuration" stage

Tags: windows, freeze

So after two two attempts to upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 on HP Probook 4320s. I gave up.
Everything goes alright until the configuration step is reached. The first time it froze when the mouse appeared. I turned the notebook off and rebooted. Win 8.1 rolled back. The second time it froze at the same step but after reboot it continued and froze at about 82% of the installation.

So Microsoft does not offer a clean install (input here a long rant about their stupid policies). What can I do now? Just forget about the update or...?
At least the rollback to Windows 8.1 is quick.

Oh, and I have another partition with Linux.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a clean install using [the media-creation/upgrade tool from Microsoft's site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).

You might need to have your license key ready if you do a clean install, though. I haven't tried it.

Comment: Are you sure? All I read is that I need to do the upgrade first to activate the license key for Win10 and only then I can do a clean install with that key.

Comment: That might be true. If you're willing to try a clean install, did you consider a clean install of 8.1 and then upgrading from there?

Comment: @Zingam You can clean install Windows 10 with Windows 7, Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 key with no problem. If it is a OEM key written in BIOS it will load the key automatically and it will choose corresponding version of Windows 10 to your older Windows version for you.